# Is it possible to draw a trasparent circle in Imagick?

Tags: php, imagick

I build graphic editor for specific tasks. Users upload scanned coins and trim background. Frontend part works great, but I have an issue with backend part. I use php Imagick with followong algo:

1. Create a transparent circle with size equal with coin and white background as a mask
2. Positioning this circle
3. Use compositeImage for merge coin image and mask

My current version use external png mask file, because I can't find a solution how to draw a transparent circle. All examples at SO use reverse method - they draw a white circle with transparent background.

UPD: this is working example.

```
$draw = new \ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor(new ImagickPixel('#ffff00'));
$draw->circle(101, 101, 200, 100);

$imagick = new \Imagick();
$imagick->newImage(202, 202, new ImagickPixel('#ffffff'));
$imagick->setImageFormat("png");
$imagick->despeckleimage();
$imagick->drawImage($draw);
$imagick->transparentPaintImage('#ffff00', 0, 1, false);

header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
```

Comment: why an external mask image? you can do some basic drawing directly in imagick: http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagickdraw.php

Comment: and to make it transparent use this link http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.transparentpaintimage.php

Comment: this doesn't work. see my updated question

Comment: rough guess: you didn't sent any transparency in your `$draw` picture, so it simply replaces whatever's in the `$imagick` picture without obeying the transparency you did set there.

Comment: I solve this problem. See my updated example. Thanks.